# Gitlab Registry Docker push fails with EOF

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-registry

So my problem is when ever i try to push a docker image to my private registry hosted/run on gitlab the push will fail with the message EOF.

Besides connection through an reverse proxy a have a standard gitlab instance in Version 11.4.7  on Ubuntu 18.04.

`docker push registry.example.com:4567/example/project`

`The push refers to repository [registry.example.com]
b927422b59f7: Preparing 
1c55a05eac35: Preparing 
8152e12d6303: Preparing 
4df94c231950: Preparing 
c8f2b48b3ca4: Preparing 
7bdc16d52fc6: Layer already exists 
0fff85bdf758: Layer already exists 
70cda07214eb: Layer already exists 
c87a43e8244d: Layer already exists 
a13e2f0a9f03: Layer already exists 
d21349b545ee: Layer already exists 
48dd4e2003bc: Layer already exists 
94fb2e0cad4e: Layer already exists 
c368c3ebd80b: Layer already exists 
004ac8bfdd61: Layer already exists 
174adb00500f: Layer already exists 
cbc7d59da4b4: Layer already exists 
22133acd47a9: Pushing [==================================================>]  50.48MB
7641974a4ba0: Layer already exists 
314e9c11d1e2: Layer already exists 
7630224de148: Layer already exists 
7ecb4828cd35: Pushing [==================================================>]  80.18MB/80.18MB
3d26624ea56e: Layer already exists 
2887f86eb343: Pushing [==================================================>]  13.47MB/13.47MB
a4ace4ed0385: Layer already exists 
fd29e0f8792a: Retrying in 5 seconds 
687dad24bb36: Pushing [==================================================>]  3.584kB
237472299760: Retrying in 7 seconds 
EOF`

**reverse proxy config**

```
server {
    listen 4567 ssl;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/registry_acces.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/registry_error.log;
    server_name gitlab.example.com
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.example.com/privkey.pem;
    root /www/;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;

            proxy_cache off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_request_buffering off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.1.15:4567;
    }

    error_page 497 301 =307 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i screwed the reverse proxy config.

With this config it is working.

```
server {
    listen *:4567;

    server_name  registry.example.com;

    server_tokens off;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/registry_acces.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/registry_error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/registry.example.com/privkey.pem;
    root /www/;

    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    ## Real IP Module Config
    ## http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.htmly
    location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_read_timeout                  900;
        proxy_pass          http://10.1.1.15:4567;
  }


}
```